# How to ingest javascript date as 'local time' then convert it to UTC and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following function:

```
var input = "December 25, 2018 01:02:20";
var fmt = 'MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss';
var currentTimeZone = "utc";

function convertUtcToLocalViceVersa() {
  console.log(input);
  var m = moment.utc(input, fmt);
  if(currentTimeZone == 'utc') {
    input = m.local().format(fmt);
    currentTimeZone = "local";
  } else {
    input = m.utc().format(fmt);
    currentTimeZone = "utc";
  }
}
```

In my HTML, I have a button that calls the function convertUtcToLocalViceVersa();

The problem I am seeing is that after hitting the button say for 5 times.. input appears to not be 'switching back and forth between utc and local' like I want. How can I make it so that it does?

NOTE: I want to make sure that each time the button is clicked, the text of 'input' is being used as opposed to a reference to a moment object.

Comment: If you pass it as a param to the `function convertUtcToLocalViceVersa()` it should work, e.g. `convertUtcToLocalViceVersa(input) `

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't. The time keeps decreasing instead of switching back and forth when you click on the button more than 2 times.

Comment: Then I suggest you post a working code snippet that reproduce the issue described

Comment: I agree with LGSon, try to provide a snippet. Anyway I think that the issue is that you are always parsing input in [UTC mode](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/), you probably have to move input parsing inside if branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are always parsing your `input` in UTC mode using [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

You have to move the parsing code inside if branches using [`moment()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) (local mode) or [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) (UTC mode) based on `currentTimeZone` value.

Here a live sample:

```js
var input = "December 25, 2018 01:02:20";
var fmt = 'MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss';
var currentTimeZone = "utc";

function convertUtcToLocalViceVersa() {
  console.log(input);
  // var m = moment.utc(input, fmt);
  if(currentTimeZone == 'utc') {
    var m = moment.utc(input, fmt);
    input = m.local().format(fmt);
    currentTimeZone = "local";
  } else {
    var m = moment(input, fmt);
    input = m.utc().format(fmt);
    currentTimeZone = "utc";
  }
  console.log(input);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="convertUtcToLocalViceVersa()">Convert</button>
```

[Local vs UTC vs Offset](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) guide is a very useful guide to understard how moment parsing works.